# How to export a Magazine Document into a PDF for PRINTING?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf, export

I know how to export an indesign document into a PDF document, but I want to make sure it is the right format for printing. I've heard about something called Booklet?

Thannk you for your answer!

Blandine

Comment: You will have to ask the firm that is going to print it. They may do their own imposition, and if so they will not be happy when receiving it in another format or order they can handle.

Answer (score 3):

For most commercial printing you should simply export to PDF/X-1a format as single pages with marks and bleeds.

If you are uncertain of PDF configuration for your print provider, you need to ask your provider how they want PDFs configured.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sending the PDF to a print service provider, it's always best to check with them to find what format they prefer. That said, PDF-X/1a is the safest PDF format for general-purpose printing, and you are unlikely to come across a print shop that can't use it.

If your booklet includes bleed, you must turn that on in the PDF dialog (under "Marks and Bleeds"). Most (not all) printers prefer that you also turn on crop marks, and it's generally safe to turn on "Use document bleed settings."

As Scott says, almost all commercial print providers want single pages so that their prepress software can set up the press sheets in the way that works best for them.

The "Booklet" output in InDesign (`File > Print Booklet`) is what you will use for local printing to an office or desktop printer, preferably one that can handle two-sided printing without your having to print one side, remove and rotate the paper, then print the other side.

You can use the PDF printer that's installed automatically with Acrobat, so that you are "printing" a PDF file. All of the usual PDF settings apply.

If your output is going to a big office laser printer with a Postscript controller such as a Fiery, check if it has an option to save the RIP file for reprinting. This allows you to print the document again directly from the printer when you need to, without having to send the PDF again from your computer.